# Django: how to filter posts based on view in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

i want to filter posts based on views e.g `view>100` that is to filter course if only the view is greater is 100 views but it keeps showing this error
`SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument`. the way i am filtering the posts is the issue but i don't know the right way to do this. I have a field `views = models.In...` in my models.py, so that is why i am trying to filter course like `course = Course.objects.filter(views>100)` then it shows the error

models.py

```
class Course(models.Model):
    course_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    pop_courses = Course.objects.filter(course_publish_status="published", views>100).order_by('?')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter with the [**`__gt`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gt):

```
Course.objects.filter(
    course_publish_status='published',
    views__gt=100
).order_by('?')
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the [`__gt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#gt) lookup to perform this filter

```
Course.objects.filter(course_publish_status="published", views__gt=100).order_by('?')
```